# jquery sticky header with resize

Tags: jquery

I'm making a sticky navbar that's going to be positioned at the bottom of the viewport on startup. I'm using `vh` units to place it. Now, if the viewport's height changes, the navbar repositions as intended. However, `.offset().top` will keep using the outdated position. That results in the script switching to sticky at incorrect positions.

```js
var win = $(window),
  header = $('nav'),
  offset = (header.offset().top);

win.scroll(function() {
  if (offset < win.scrollTop()) {
    header.addClass("sticky");
  } else {
    header.removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#boxi {
  z-index: -15;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: green;
}
#boxi2 {
  z-index: -15;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: pink;
}
nav {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50vh;
  transform: translate(0, -50px);
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  color: white;
}
nav.sticky {
  transform: translate(0, 0px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="container">
  <div id="boxi"></div>
  <nav>Sticky!</nav>
  <div id="boxi2"></div>
</body>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/philipchaoui/4whfz14j/2/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4whfz14j/6/ -> is this you want accomplish?

Comment: Yeah perfect, thank you, all the answers are working but I says I should not just say "thanks"! Anyway every solution works great!

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your offset is not being updated after your window resizes. Thus the addClass/removeClass will trigger once you scroll past the original point. Thankfully you can just add the following to the end of your code to get that fixed:

```
win.on('resize',function(){
    offset = (header.offset().top);
});
```

This insures that your offset will be updated everytime your window resizes, thus keeping things in sync.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4whfz14j/5/)

Answer (score 0):

use a window `.resize` Jquery function. it will fire on resize the target.

```js
var win = $(window),
    header = $('nav'),
    offset = (header.offset().top);

win.scroll(function() {
    if (offset < win.scrollTop()) {
        header.addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        header.removeClass("sticky");
    }
}),

win.resize(function () {
  offset = header.offset().top;
})
```

```css
#container{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}  

#boxi {
  z-index: -15;
  height:50vh;
  background-color:green;
}

#boxi2{
  z-index: -15;
  height:1000px;
  background-color:pink;
}

nav {
  width:100%;  
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  top:50vh;
  transform: translate(0,-50px);
  background-color:black;
  opacity:0.5;
  color:white;
}

nav.sticky {
  transform: translate(0, 0px);
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  left:0px;
  z-index:999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body id="container">
    <div id="boxi"></div>
    <nav>Sticky!</nav>
    <div id="boxi2"></div>
</body>
```